# Requesting the reopening of "What type of plant is Léon's plant?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, closed-questions, trivia

I would like to request the reopening of the question, “[What type of plant is Léon's plant?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76569/1006)”, which was closed as off-topic for the reason that “trivia questions are off-topic”. The “trivia” close reason is outdated and no longer in line with site policy, as the community reached a consensus years ago that trivia questions are no longer off-topic. The question is relevant and interesting, and it could enrich the appreciation and enjoyment of the film for future visitors who might have the same curiosity.

[The community changed its position on trivia questions years ago and decided to allow them](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006), so [the trivia close reason is no longer applicable](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006). The question has value, and it does not fall under any of our existing question closing reasons.

Unfortunately, [the question was left closed in the reopen review queue](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/95506) as “original close reason(s) were not resolved”, which I find puzzling considering the community consensus on trivia questions.

I am concerned that the current reopen votes will expire soon. Can I get some votes to reopen here, or at least a clear explanation of why it is still considered off-topic?

Here are some of the relevant meta posts where the community agreed to stop closing trivia questions as off-topic:

- [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006)
- [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1827/1006)
- [The term "trivia" is just lazy. Can't we do better?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4514/1006)
- [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006)

Comment: Done.  Thanks for the Q.

Comment: It's been reopened now. It's not entirely clear why certain individuals fought so hard to keep it closed, in spite of the meta ruling on trivia questions; https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/timeline

Comment: @Valorum I also find it baffling why certain individuals, including a moderator, [persist in keeping these “trivia” questions closed](//movies.stackexchange.com/posts/76569/revisions), contrary to community consensus. I also don’t understand the downvotes on this and other meta posts that request the reopening of such questions. None of the downvoters have posted an answer to explain their rationale for keeping these questions closed. It seems like they are unhappy with the community consensus on “trivia” questions and are venting their frustration by downvoting meta posts that support it.

Comment: @galacticninja - I made that point in a comment the other day. It's borderline abusive to use a downvote as a surrogate close vote on question *types* that you don't like. Not to mention unfriendly as hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>(I posted an answer to prevent this [meta discussion from being automatically deleted by the Community bot (AKA “Roomba”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/162827). Since the question has a negative score due to downvotes, it would have been deleted by the bot, dismissing it entirely.)</sup>

As of Oct. 24, 2023, “[What type of plant is Léon's plant?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76569/1006)” has been reopened, respecting the community consensus on “trivia” questions. Thank you to everyone who voted to reopen.

Comment: If "*respecting the community consensus*" was a valid argument, identification questions would still be allowed :)