# Are questions about the works of directors/actors/writers on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I realized, that I asked two questions, that are not specific to a concrete movie, but to the general works of a director:

- [Did Hayao Miyazaki make any movie without an environmental theme?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28/66)
- [Did Kurosawa make so many Shakespeare-adaptations to avoid censorship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/29/66)

Nobody objected or tried to close. So they seem OK. Should we codify that in the [FAQ](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/66)?

My suggestion:

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - The works of a director / an actor / a writer related to movies

Answer (score 10):

Good suggestion. Questions about the people in/behind movies are more than acceptable in my opinion, *as long as they refer to movies in some way*.

In other words, I think a question like "Where was Matt Damon born?" would not be acceptable here, but something along the lines of "Did Matt Damon do all his own stunts in the Bourne series?" is a fine, on-topic question.

Comment: Yes, that's why the addition in parentheses.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't follow from the one preceding it. Did you mean *more than acceptable* or *not acceptable*?

Comment: @Tshepang I mean that the question "Where was Matt Damon born?" has nothing to do with movies so it's not a good fit here. But a question about Matt Damon that related to his movies (in general or a specific movie) is good.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, did matt damon do all those stunts?

Answer (score 3):

I have no problem with questions relating to anything that has to do with making the actual film.

If it turns into **"Did Linsay Lohan have her baby this month"**  Then that will be off-topic.

However, I assume **"Did Lindsay Lohan have her baby on the set of Mean Girls 5: The return of the mean"**  Then that would be On-Topic as something like this can affect filming and the like.