# Why are questions about locating or purchasing movie or TV content not allowed?

Tags: support, scope, close-reasons

I find that [locating or purchasing movie or TV content is not allowed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Why is that? Searching in Google with this query [`site:movies.meta.stackexchange.com locating or purchasing movie or TV content`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02Z4D6g2U9otEgZuwiEMIOqZsZJnA%3A1591978918807&ei=pqvjXo7nMKCVr7wP2Maf6A8&q=site%3Amovies.meta.stackexchange.com+locating+or+purchasing+movie+or+TV+content&oq=site%3Amovies.meta.stackexchange.com+locating+or+purchasing+movie+or+TV+content&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1CwigFY25UBYOmYAWgAcAF4AIABnQGIAcwFkgEDMS41mAEAoAEBoAECqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiO0sfP1_zpAhWgyosBHVjjB_0Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) doesn't yield any useful information.

In my case, I want to find a movie scene that illustrates an idea about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down.

PS: The question is asked here: [Is there any movie scene about helping a rival to their maximum potential before taking them down?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/109575/46929)

Answer (score 5):

"I want to find a good movie scene that illustrates X" is IMHO either a recommendation question (which are off-topic) or a sort of identification question (also off-topic).

Comment: by "good", I mean it can fully illustrate the concept, not just half illustrate it. I agree the word is vague though. Can you explain why you don't agree with Glorfindel's answer? Also, can you explain why identification questions are bad? It seems that the site [used to accept them](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/46929).

Comment: @Ooker I'm not sure why you think this answer disagrees with Glorfindel's answer, which doesn't really say that your question is okay either.

Comment: ID questions were banned almost 2.5 years ago: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I believe there is a strong reason for the mod team to stick to the decision despite of being heavily downvoted in [the ban post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions "We are discontinuing support for identification questions - Movies &amp; TV Meta Stack Exchange"). Perhaps adding a quick note at the top explaining why the decision is still valid in spite of the votes may help clearing confusion. I'm sorry for not having read it carefully though. I know it's important

Comment: @NapoleonWilson he said: "otherwise it's not unlike the questions in the first-appearance tag". I'm not sure how to understand it other than "first-appearance questions are fine. Yours is either." (Just in case: I agree the word "good" is not good)

Comment: @Ooker Despite what this answer or its comments suggest, I don't actually think the decision about identification questions is even relevant here anyway. That's not really what you're asking for. You're just asking to find example scenes for a general fuzzily defined concept. That seems a straight-up recommendation/location request we have never really done here, even before identification questions were abolished. But I'll try to post a longer answer when I can find the time for it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find a good movie scene that illustrates an idea about helping a rival to their maximum potential before take them down.

That's not what is meant by locating or purchasing movie or TV content; what *is* meant is something like "I want to watch The Shawshank Redemption online, where can I do this?" Such questions are likely to yield answers with links to pirated content, or depend too much on the geographical location of the viewer or (over time) become obsolete, as @RayButterworth notes in the comments.

Your hypothetical question might be closed as opinion-based (what defines a 'good' movie scene is to a certain extent depending on opinion), but otherwise it's not unlike the questions in the [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance) tag.

Comment: As irony would have it, I'm now actually watching The Shawshank Redemption on Dutch public television. I swear I didn't look at the schedule before posting this answer...

Comment: It's not only the geographical location that matters. There's also the temporal location.  A correct answer today will likely be useless in the not too distant future.  (E.g. suppose the perfect answer were "The tape is available for rent at Blockbuster.")

Comment: by "good", I mean it can fully illustrate the concept, not just half illustrate it. I agree the word is vague though. Anyway, do you have any suggestion for tags? For now I use [tag:trope]

Comment: @Ooker looks fine to me (but I don't have much knowledge about tagging here).