# How to migrate questions to SFF?

Tags: support

How to migrate questions to SFF?

And is it can only be done by moderators or also users can?

Comment: First of all, questions older than 60 days are not migrated. Second, it requires a moderator to migrate them. However, if you're looking for a way to get all your contributions migrated to another site, that won't be feasible IMO.

Comment: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 3):

At the moment [it's being proposed](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4090/4297) for a formal Migration Path.

Currently only Mods can do the migration. if a Migration Path is set up between Movies and TV and SciFi you can vote to migrate by:

Voting to Close > off-topic because... > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

SciFi.SE will appear here (currently only Movies and TV Meta Appears here)

Note that SciFi only want Science Fiction and Fantasy Questions so ID Requests have to show that they are Science Fiction and Fantasy. also their mods can reject a migration effectively closing it here aswell and as per [the Meta SE Answer on Migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/250962) the migrations might be rejected automatically if there is no matching tags unless a Mod does the migration.

Also:

> After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, very rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.

as such any existing Science Fiction and Fantasy ID Requests that could go there can not be migrated by anyone but Stack Exchange Employees (they have Diamonds on every site even when they have never posted anything)

Comment: The link in the first line of your answer leads back to ... this question. Was that what you meant to link to?

Comment: @Randal'Thor oh thanks for pointing that out (dam clipboard) but i suspect you knew it was supposed to go to yours

Comment: I think the question you link to *doesn't* actually propose a migration path, though (in contrast to the one on Anime and the one that sparked it on SciFi, so the confusion is understandable.)

Comment: Ah, no, I didn't realise that was what it was supposed to go to! My meta post is *not* a proposal for a formal migration path. Quoting from it: "*When an ID question is flagged for migration to SFF, by a user who's active on SFF and knows its scope, migrate it over there. [...] It does mean the workload of migration has to be entirely on diamond mods - the alternative being to set up a migration path which any five 3k+ rep users could use*" Of course, it's in the same ballpark, so if someone posts an answer proposing a migration path and that gets enough support ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor ahh sorry. i thought it was the same, maybe i was thinking of the Anime and Manga one because of similar situation. banned id requests and scifi.se wants to keep the scifi/fantasy ones. but maybe it's my understanding of migrations being incorrect but don'y scifi/se users who aren't mods still need the formal migration path set to flag for migration?

Comment: @Memor-X No. It's about a general moderator flag, *not* about a close-flag. You can always issue general moderator flags.