# Why was my non-science fiction question moved to Science Fiction & Fantasy?

Tags: support, identify, migration

Last year, I posted the following TV-show identification question on the site:

> What show did Yakko, Wakko, and Dot make frequent silent cameos in?
>
> *Animaniacs* was an animated TV show made in the 90's about the Warner siblings, Yakko, Wakko, and Dot.  But I don't think that is the only TV show I've seen Yakko, Wakko, and Dot in.  I have a distinct memory of these three characters appearing in another 90's animated TV show, where they were often shown running around, with no dialogue.  Can someone help me identify it?
>
> At least my recollection is that the  show is *Tiny Toon Adventures*.  Now *Tiny Adventures* ran from 1990 to 1992, whereas *Animaniacs* ran from 1993 to 1998.  But they were both Warner Bros. shows, so it's possible that toward the end of the *Tiny Toon Adventures* run they were showing cameos of *Animaniacs* characters to lead into the new show.  Can anyone confirm this?
>
> Now it's possible that I'm misremembering, and the show I'm thinking of is actually *Pinky and the Brain*.  After all, *Pinky and the Brain* was a spinoff of *Animaniacs*, so it makes sense that you would have *Animaniacs* cameos in *Pinky and the Brain*.

I just found out that it was [moved](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180711/16093) to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stackexchange.  But as you can see my question has nothing to do with the science fiction or fantasy genres.  So what’s going on?

As part of TV Shows and Movies Stack Exchange discontinuing identification requests, were identification requests automatically moved to Science Fiction and Fantasy without regard to relevance?

Comment: You should ask this question on Scifi Fantasy Meta. They chose which questions to migrate from our site to theirs. They made a list of questions which are eligible for their scope and asked CMs' for migration. It's done. They will answer you clearly because it's a question of their scope. Anyways, the show you mentioned falls under Children _fantasy_ shows. That might be the reason.

Comment: @NogShine Oh ok, I didn’t know that had happened.

Comment: @NogShine And I don’t Animaniacs really qualifies as fantasy, children’s or otherwise.

Comment: As I said already, SFF meta will answer your question accurately.

Comment: [Which ID questions do we want from Movies & TV?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11659/which-id-questions-do-we-want-from-movies-tv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> were identification requests automatically moved to Science Fiction and Fantasy without regard to relevance?

**No.** The process for moving those questions over was the one outlined in [this related meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4090/49). Basically, we had the users of **SciFi.SE gather a list** of all the questions they would be willing to take, since they are the ones **best-versed in the intricacies of their site's own scope**. There was of course a certain level of trust in those users' awareness of their own site scope and the avid involvement of their community to ensure a reasonable topicality consensus. But they are the only ones to reliably assess what questions are on- or off-topic. They created such a list [on their meta site](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11659/23386) and we mass-**migrated all the questions *they wanted*** and that we would have otherwise deleted.

If you disagree with the question being on-topic on SciFi.SE, you have a few options to argue the result of that migration, none of which involve *this site*, though:

- You can **debate its topicality on [Science Fiction & Fantasy Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/)** to enquire why they deemed it on-topic (and seem to still do, although I can't see if there have been any close-votes on it yet) and discuss *if* it should be and what to do with the question.
- If you're sure it's off-topic, you can be more proactive and **close-vote your question** right away, possibly *inciting* a fruitful scope discussion (or maybe just have it closed by the rest of the community, in case they agree with you but somehow missed the question for whatever reason).
- You *could* delete the question altogether (which would also have been the *sole alternative to migration*). However, I would strongly advise against that since that wouldn't be an all too constructive approach to the problem and you're generally **not supposed to delete content that the rest of the community deems valuable**.

However, all the above scenarios would and should play out **entirely inside the SciFi.SE community**, since they *actively asked* for this question and with that requested and approved migration it has since been **off our plates**. As said, the alternative to migrating it would have been deleting it into the empty void of nothingness forevermore.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I’ll just do nothing at this point.