# Can this old ID question of mine get migrated to SciFi.SE, please?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

About three years ago, when I first joined, I asked this ID question: [Cartoon in which Donald Duck tries to stop another duck from committing suicide](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/68761/46980). When ID questions were made off-topic in early 2018, the sci-fi ones were all migrated to SciFi.SE, where they're still on-topic, but mine must have gotten missed, and I only just remembered it.

As per SciFi Meta consensus, [Donald Duck](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11528/76048), [Looney Tunes](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12319/76048) etc. are on-topic there. I can't flag the question, so I'm posting here just to ask: would it be possible to migrate it to SciFi.SE and re-open it? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it, there are a lotf of SFF ID questions still on M&TV (cf https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie?tab=Votes). Why is it especially important that this one, who happens to match the apparent criteria of staying (it's detailed enough, and had an answer), should be migrated to SFF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When identification questions were discontinued here, not all of them were migrated/deleted. There were criteria for keeping high quality ones that received proper answers as detailed in [this related meta question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4138/49), which were closed and locked but not deleted. About ~1000 such questions are still around and yours falls under these criteria, too. **Only those that would otherwise have been deleted were candidates for migration** and were migrated in bulk after undergoing a [manual review process by the SciFi.SE community](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4090/49).

I'm afraid migrating questions that were deemed valuable enough to stay around as historical artifacts after 3 years now isn't something we're going to bother with, nor is it possible for moderators to even do without the help of SE employees (as only questions younger than 60 days can be migrated easily).

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Figured it was worth asking.