# Why wasn't a movie identification site created?

Tags: discussion, identify

Everybody needs movie identification; every existing method doesn't work, and most movie identification problems can be solved quickly on SE.

Movies & TV SE doesn't allow such questions, and Science Fiction & Fantasy SE only allows questions about specific genres. Such a specific identification site on SE should have been created or tried to be created before. The fact that it still doesn't exist indicates there are some problems with such a site. What could these problems be?

If it is about managing difficulties, then the reviewing rule can be dramatically simplified on this site, or even no human review at all, only some machine review to statistically remove the most serious flood of bad/spam Q&As.

Comment: If you want such a site you are welcome to go ahead and create one. See https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also - https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/how-can-i-find-the-title-of-a-movie-from-just-a-description-or-image

Comment: @Paulie_D It's like if someone has done this before and failed, it's better to learn the reason before trying it.

Comment: @Paulie_D All methods in that page doesn't work well or is not accessible.

Comment: You are welcome to search "identification" here and you will see the **extensive** discussions about M&TV and this subject. There is no need to re-hash those discussions.

Comment: @Paulie_D I will do that.

Comment: Well, and honestly, there are legitimate debates about applicability for other people, especially since memories of media can be very idiosyncratic, and ID questions do seem to lend toward the "new user posts the question, never comes back, and we'll never know if the right piece was identified", as is often seen on the SF&F SE. That said, I _like_ answering ID questions even if it can be a bit thankless.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - It's pretty clear that *certain users* were opposed to them. For the record, on SFF:SE, it's more often than not that the user has their question answered and accepts it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A movie identification SE site was actually created. This one. Movies & TV SE used to accept movie identification questions, as you can see from this meta post: [Shall we ban identification questions?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2250/1006) However, this policy changed in January 2018, as announced in this meta post: [We are discontinuing support for identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/1006). The reason for this change was apparently a shift in community consensus, which expressed “unanimous dissatisfaction with the current situation as well as broad agreement that they are not worth the trouble anymore”, citing the community consensus at the time in this 2017 meta post: [Check in on Identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4054/1006).

However, if you look at the votes on the answers to those meta posts, you will notice that community consensus has changed since 2017–2018. The answers that argue against banning identification questions have significantly more upvotes than those that support the ban. I think this shows that the community has reconsidered its stance on identification questions. Those who want to keep the ban no longer have the support of the community consensus.

---

Some possible ways to handle problematic ID questions are to follow the example of SF&F SE and create a [FAQ meta post that guides users on how to ask good identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957). For instance, we could have a post titled “Tips for asking identification questions” that lists the essential details to include in such questions, such as the approximate year, the genre, the plot, the characters, the setting, etc. We could also add a [tag warning for the identification tag(s)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12591/7957) that reminds users to check the FAQ post and provide essential details before posting their questions. For the questions that are too vague to be answered, we could still use the close reason “needs details or clarity” and ask the OP to edit their question with more information.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to allow 'Identify-this' questions again, but I doubt the site's moderators would allow that to be put to a vote.

Comment: @Valorum Perhaps the active members of the community should demand new site moderators then?

Comment: @Skooba - A new broom sweeps clean, as they say

Comment: "We could also add a tag warning for the identification tag(s)" Like I said elsewhere: when this site allowed ID questions, almost every day I visited I would see an ID question despite me filtering out the various ID tags, because these fly-by-night users *did not use the ID tag*. As for "we could still use the close reason 'needs details or clarity'": I have read numerous times in meta how closing a question is "bad" because it angers the user and is unwelcoming etc.